# register locale css file in master page in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

How can i register locale css file in master page with using SharePoint Designer in website having different variations.

Like following line render style library folder

masterpage :

render: http://localSP/Style Library/MyFolder/sn.css (Correct)

How can i register css in master page so that it provide following

required render: http://localSP/Style Library/fr-FR/MyFolder/sn.css (if its French varition)

masterpage :

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to manually create that css file under french variation.  fr-FR is a sub-site, so try to navigate there and put the artifact there.

Comment: Btw, the inclusion for the CSS can be achieved as following:
  
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<asp:Literal Text='<%$ SPUrl:~SiteCollection/~language/Style Library/My Folder/sn.css %>' runat='server'/>" type="text/javascript" />`